# Is there a way to set a limit for the time in C?

Tags: c

I´m doing a game in C, the program shows you an operation like 5+10 and you have to answer correctly, the thing is that i want to put a limit to the user so he can only have like 10 seconds to answer. Is there a way to do that in C?

I´ve tried using the header time.h, like putting a variable time_1 that is the actual time and then a second variable time_2 adding like 10 seconds to actual time that variable so while time_1 is less than time_2 I can put something, but C doesn´t allow me to put something while this is happening.

Comment: To "simultaneously" wait for input and count down a timer, you would need two threads operating in parallel -- one to do each of those two things. The way to achieve that in C depends on the operating system environment in which you are working.

Comment: For gcc, `select` with a timeout set in the `timeval` struct provides a very simple way to do this. There will be similar ways to implement this on other OSs. For windows you can look at [Synchronous and Overlapped Pipe I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/synchronous-and-overlapped-input-and-output) What OS is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {

    int sec = 10;
    int duration, acc = 0;

    int x;

    printf("5+10\n");

    // kbhit is a function that checks whether the keyboard is pressed
    while (!_kbhit()) {

        duration = (clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        if (duration >= acc) {
            if (acc >= sec) break;
            acc += 1;
        }
    }

    if (acc >= sec) printf("game over");

    else {
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        if (x == 15) printf("win");
        else printf("game over");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

You may want this kind of code.

_kbhit is a function that checks whether the keyboard is pressed

If any key is pressed, it returns a value other than zero.

Comment: Not that there is much portability concerning in this area, but `conio.h` makes sure it is 100% non-portable. The DOS `conio.h` header is one, all things being equal, that should be avoided in favor of a standard header.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set a limit for the time in C?

For "pure standard portable C", no.

For "C extended by other standards" (e.g. POSIX, Win32), some of the possibilities are:

- use many very small delays, checking for user input between each very small delay (e.g. 1000 delays at 10 milliseconds each)
- use `alarm()` to get a signal (`SIGALARM`) after 10 seconds, so that your "wait for user input" gets interrupted by the signal if/when the time-out expires
- use something like `select()` to wait for input (to read from the `stdin`) with a time-out.